# Is it possible to get a router’s IP address from a Wi-Fi signal?

Tags: wireless-router, ip, broadcast

Is it possible to get a router’s IP address from a Wi-Fi signal without having to connect in, given that it's broadcasting Wi-Fi, but requires a WPA password?

Answer (score 8):

**You can't:**

And it's simply, [IEEE 802.11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) and variants work in Layer 2 and Layer 1 in the [OSI Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model).

To be able to discover another host using UDP datagrams, TCP packets, or even ICMP, you need third-layer connectivity.

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe so. You can find it's MAC address but I don't believe you will get the IP address until you have successfully connected.